# proftpd does not ask for passphrase

Tags: proftpd

I configured tls for proftpd

- I uncomment the line `Include /etc/proftpd/tls.conf`  in the file `/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf`
- I configured `tls.conf
  [image]

However, it seems to not start correctly. I use `sudo service proftpd restart`. No error message displayed afterwards. I also tried `sudo /etc/init.d/proftpd start` which returns `[ ok ] Starting proftpd (via systemctl): proftpd.service.`

However, I does not seem that proftpd is running:

```
sudo ps -ef | grep proftpd
xxx_user  4871   665  0 17:46 pts/0    00:00:00 grep proftpd

sudo cat proftpd.log
2019-11-26 16:40:56,056 xxx proftpd[3362] xxx_URL: ProFTPD 1.3.6 (stable) (built Wed Oct 23 2019 14:22:38 UTC) standalone mode STARTUP
2019-11-26 16:45:43,902 xxx proftpd[3362] xxx_URL.de: ProFTPD killed (signal 15)
2019-11-26 16:45:43,904 xxx proftpd[3362] xxx_URL: ProFTPD 1.3.6 standalone mode SHUTDOWN
```

All other log files are empty and `tls.log` file does not exist.

I also run an apache2 server on the machine which uses the same certificates. however, there I always have to enter the passphrase when I restart apache. Why is proftpd not asking for the passphrase and why does it not work?

Comment: try to run proftpd eith drbug or directly wuthout let it go into background and also check befote syslog

Comment: do you get more verbose logging if you run "sudo systemctl status proftpd" and "journalctl -u proftpd"?